# MySQL - How to make a statement AND IFNULL

Tags: mysql

how do I make this statement `AND IFNULL`?

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,a.date_of_birth,CURDATE()) >=  '' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,a.date_of_birth,CURDATE()) <= ''`:

Using `AND` or `OR` only messes my select statement.

Comment: Can you show by way of sample data what you are trying to do here?  `TIMESTAMPDIFF` with `YEAR` as the unit should be returning a number, not a string, but in any case certainly not an empty string.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hey Tim, I want to make the statement to become optional if it's empty. Whenever I use `AND`, it ignores my other `IFNULL` statements. Using `OR` also messes my `SELECT` statement. Sorry if I sound unclear.

Comment: Still no data :-(  ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but maybe `COALESCE` is what you want?

[MySQL COALESCE FUNCTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,a.date_of_birth,CURDATE()) , '')
```